# Can I access Azure AD graph api and Azure management resources using the same accessToken

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

It looks like if I create a token using "https://management.core.windows.net" as the resource ID then I won't be able to use the same accessToken against the graph API. Is there a way to avoid calling the AcquireTokenAsync more than once?

```
AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.core.windows.net", "<some_client_id>, new Uri("https://localhost"), new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Always)).Result;

TaskCompletionSource<string> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
tcs.SetResult(result.AccessToken);
ActiveDirectoryClient graphClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(new Uri("https://graph.windows.net/" + result.TenantId),
() => { return tcs.Task; });
foreach (var app in graphClient.Applications.ExecuteAsync().Result.CurrentPage)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{app.AppId}, {app.DisplayName}");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Azure AD access token is only good for a single resource, so the short answer is no.

However, you do benefit from the fact that Azure AD issues [multi-resource refresh tokens](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/10/14/adal-windows-azure-ad-and-multi-resource-refresh-tokens/), which means that obtaining an access token for the second resource is simply a call to the AAD token endpoint, and not the full authentication flow.